# TextBox to DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net

I need to solve this little problem.

In my country (Serbia) we have JMBG (that`s Unique Number of Citizen a.k.a. Citizen ID Number)
That JMBG contains 13 numbers and first 7 numbers are date of birth.
Example:
My JMBG is 2911990710***
29 for 29th, 11 for November and 990 for year 1990.

Now, my problem is, when I write my JMBG I need to get back value of my birthdate in DateTimePicker bellow TextBox in form, how to do that?

EDIT: I don know why this is migrate to StackOverFlow from Programming when I need CODE EXAMPLE

Comment: its possible to parse a string to get the values and pass them to a datetime object.

Comment: I know that, but I need code example.

Comment: parse a string http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 & create a datetime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/5052/asdasdasdne.png
This is screenshot. JMBG is TextBox where have to be entered 13 digits number, and 'Datum Rodjenja' is Birthdate DateTimePicker.
I just need whole example of code to add into the rest of the code to work as I wrote in question

Comment: @Ryathal that links are good but I can`t find anything about mixing these two...

Comment: `Visual studio` tag doesn't tell us a thing about what technology you're working with. Is this winforms/asp.net/something else? Are you using c#? VB.NET? Please edit the tags appropriately.

Comment: I've set it back to VB.Net for you. You didn't mean vb6 did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in harry so fast code (you have to check by your own for some things):

```
    Dim sJMBG As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim sBDate = sJMBG.Substring(0, 7)
    Dim sThous As String = sBDate(4) 'The number specifying if we are in 2000 or in 1900
    Dim iThous As Integer
    iThous = Integer.Parse(sThous)
    sBDate = If(iThous = 9, sBDate.Insert(4, 1), sBDate.Insert(4, 2))

    Dim dat As New Date(sBDate.Substring(4, 4), sBDate.Substring(2, 2), sBDate.Substring(0, 2))
    DateTimePicker1.Value = dat
```

Let me know if you need anything more.